# Kendo Angular Popup gives 'HTMLAnchorElement is not assignable to type ElementRef'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

Using Kendo UI for Angular and getting a warning from my analysis in WebStorm.  Here is the code:

```
  <a #profileSelector (click)="ProfileSelectorOpen = true">
    <img [src]="User.profileImages.sizeX40" alt="Profile Pic" height="40px" *ngIf="User!=null">
  </a>
  <kendo-popup #popup [anchor]="profileSelector"
               (anchorViewportLeave)="ProfileSelectorOpen=false"
               *ngIf="ProfileSelectorOpen"
               style="max-width: 600px; min-width: 300px">
    ...The popup content...
  </kendo-popup>
```

It's telling me `Type HTMLAnchorElement is not assignable to type ElementRef` on the `[anchor]` of the `kendo-popup` tag.  What's strange is that I have the same thing (at least as far as I can see) in another location and it's working fine without a warning.  Here is that code:

```
<a #projectSelector (click)="ShowPopup()"
   style="margin: 1em 0; color: black; font-weight: bold"
   *ngIf="CurrentCompany!=null && SelectedProject != null">
  {{CurrentCompany.name}} &#9660; {{SelectedProject.Name}}
</a>
<kendo-popup #popup [anchor]="projectSelector"
             (anchorViewportLeave)="ProjectSelectorOpen=false"
             *ngIf="ProjectSelectorOpen"
             style="max-width: 600px; min-width: 400px">
  ...the popup content...
</kendo-popup>
```

The popup works fine as is but trying to clean up the warning. Anyone know why it would be giving me this?